# Create tables using command windows SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, datatable, command-window

I wanted to use tables from here https://github.com/prograhammer/countries-regions-cities

My command line looks like this

```
sqlcmd -S SERVERNAME -d DATABASENAME -i script.sql
```

I navigate to the folder with the unzipped script from given website.
It runs, it does not show any errors, but when I open my SQL server, I can't see new tables on my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script is for MySQL, while you tagged your question for SQL Server. This isn't valid Transact SQL and you can't execute it on SQL Server. So you do not see new tables, because your script failed.